# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable When trying to get sum and average of a GPA List

Tags: python

I am working on a GPA Calculator, It's almost finished but this one error keeps dragging me back. I get the TypeError "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I know it's probably due to the float values in the gpas dict but I do not know how to fix it. My code is down below.

```
def courses():
p = 0
classes = []
while p <= 5:
    name = input('Please enter the name of the class :')
    classes.append(name)
    p += 1
print(classes)
func()


def func():
    g = 0
    score = 0
    gpas = {'A+': 4.0,
        'A': 4.0,
        'B+': 3.7,
        'B': 3.3,
        'B-': 3.0,
        'C+': 2.7,
        'C': 2.3,
        'C-': 2.0,
        'D+': 1.7,
        'D': 1.3,
        'D-': 1.0,
        'F': 0.0,
        }
    while g <= 5:
        grades = []
        grade = input('Enter your letter grade, in order of   class listed :')
        grade = grade.upper()
        grades.append(grade)
        g += 1
        for grade in grades:
            score = sum(gpas[grade])
            return float(score + [grade] for grade in grades) / 6      
    print(score)
```

courses()

Comment: `sum` takes an iterable like a `list` or `tuple`. You're applying the grade value which is a `float`.

Comment: Ok thanks, how can I fix the return float(score + [grade] for grade in grades) / 6 ?

Comment: The previous commenter  was explaining that this line is throwing the error: `score = sum(gpas[grade])`. `sum` takes a list, you're feeding it a float.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the indentation problems and properly calculated the average. Changed your `while` loops to instead use `for` loops. Removed static variables.

```
def courses(number_of_classes):
    classes = []
    for i in range(number_of_classes):  # Use range to automatically increment index
        name = input('Please enter the name of the class :')
        classes.append(name)
    average_gpa = func(number_of_classes)
    print (average_gpa)


def func(number_of_classes):
    gpas = {'A+': 4.0,
        'A': 4.0,
        'B+': 3.7,
        'B': 3.3,
        'B-': 3.0,
        'C+': 2.7,
        'C': 2.3,
        'C-': 2.0,
        'D+': 1.7,
        'D': 1.3,
        'D-': 1.0,
        'F': 0.0,
        }
    grades = []

    for i in range(number_of_classes):  # using range to automatically increse index
        grade = input('Enter your letter grade, in order of class listed : ')
        grade = grade.upper()
        grades.append(gpas[grade]) # get the float value for the frade

    score = float(sum(grades))/number_of_classes  # Sum adds all values in an iterable, divide by total number to get average
    return score

courses(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactor your code and added some comments:

```
def courses():
    p = 0
    classes = []
    while p <= 5:
        name = input('Please enter the name of the class :')
        classes.append(name)
        p += 1
    print(classes)
    avg_grade = func(classes)
    # Print avg_grade with float 2 number
    print('avg_grade: ', "{:.1f}".format(avg_grade))


def func(classes):
    g = 0
    # Changed letter GPA
    gpas = {
        'A+': 4.0,
        'A': 3.7,
        'B+': 3.33,
        'B': 3,
        'B-': 2.7,
        'C+': 2.3,
        'C': 2,
        'C-': 1.7,
        'D+': 1.3,
        'D': 1,
        'D-': 0.7,
        'F': 0.0,
    }

    # List of number grades
    grades = []
    while g < len(classes):
        # Added class name
        grade = input(f'Enter your letter grade of {classes[g]}:')
        grade = grade.upper()
        # Check valid letter grade
        if grade in gpas:
            grades.append(gpas[grade])
            g += 1
        else:
            # Require re-enter valid letter
            valid_letters = ', '.join(gpas.keys())
            print('Please enter a valid letter grade. The valid letters is: ', valid_letters)

    return sum(grades) / len(classes)

courses()
```